# If i rotate a picture, it messes up my rectangles, and i cannot pick a picture correctly

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, draw, rect

I have the following on Draw method:

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //        super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint); //Deseneaza Bitmapul mutabil
    if (PaintActivity.isPic == 1) {
        rect = new Rect((int)mX, (int)mY, ((int)mX+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getWidth()), ((int)mY+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getHeight()));
        rectscale = new Rect((int)mX-20, (int)mY-20, (int)mX+20, (int)mY+20);
        rectrotate = new Rect((int)((mX+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getWidth())-20), (int)mY-20, (int)(mX+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getHeight()+20), (int)mY+20);
        for(int i=0;i<bitmaps.size();i++){
            if((lastBitmap != i)&& (bitmaps.get(i)!= null) ){
                if(bitmaps.get(i).isRotate){
                    matrixRotate.setRotate(bitmaps.get(i).rectrotateVal, bitmaps.get(i).pX+(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getWidth() / 2), bitmaps.get(i).pY+(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getHeight() / 2)); //rotate it
                }else{
                    matrixRotate.setRotate(0, bitmaps.get(i).pX+(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getWidth() / 2), bitmaps.get(i).pY+(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getHeight() / 2)); //rotate it
                }
                canvas.setMatrix(matrixRotate);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap, bitmaps.get(i).pX,  bitmaps.get(i).pY, mBitmapPaint);
                canvas.setMatrix(null);
                canvas.drawCircle(bitmaps.get(i).pX, bitmaps.get(i).pY, 10, cPaint);
                canvas.drawCircle(bitmaps.get(i).pX+bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getWidth(), bitmaps.get(i).pY, 10, cPaint);
            }
        }
        if (bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap != null) {
            bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).rectscale = rectscale;
            bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).rectrotate = rectrotate;
            if(isScalling){
                rect = new Rect((int)mX,(int) mY, (int)tempx, (int)tempy);
                int w = Math.abs(rect.width());
                int h = Math.abs(rect.height());
                canvas.drawRect(rect, rPaint);
                if((w!=0)&&(h!=0)){
                    bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap2, h, w, bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getConfig());
                }
            }
            if(isRotating){
                rotateVal = (float) 45;
                bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).rectrotateVal = rotateVal;
                bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).isRotate = isRotating;
                matrixRotate.setRotate(rotateVal, mX+(bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getWidth() / 2), mY+(bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getHeight() / 2)); //rotate it
                canvas.setMatrix(matrixRotate);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap,  mX, mY, mBitmapPaint);
                canvas.setMatrix(null);
                canvas.drawCircle(bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).pX+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getWidth(), bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).pY, 10, cPaint);
                canvas.drawRect(bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).rect, rPaint);
            }else{
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap, mX, mY, mBitmapPaint);
                canvas.drawCircle(mX, mY, 10, cPaint);
                canvas.drawCircle(mX+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getWidth(), mY, 10, cPaint);
            }
            bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).pX = mX;
            bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).pY = mY;
            bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).rect = rect;
            bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).rectscale = rectscale;
            bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).rectrotate = rectrotate;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<textArray.size();j++){
            if (textArray.get(j) != null) {
                canvas.drawText(textArray.get(j), tXArray.get(j), tYArray.get(j), textPaintArray.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a number of bitmaps, the "rect" rectangle is the same width and height of the picture, so that if i press a picture, it sets me on it, to move it.
rectscale = is a rectangle situated in the left-top corner of the picture, where i draw a circle, if i press the circle, then i can scale my picture.
rectrotate = same thing but in the right-top corner of the picture. i press it, it rotates my picture with 45degrees.
I have the following touch events:

```
private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    if(PaintActivity.isPic == 1){
        if(bitmaps.size() > 0){
            for(int i = 0;i<(bitmaps.size()-1);i++){
                if(bitmaps.get(i).rect.contains((int)mX,(int) mY)){
                    lastBitmap = i;
                }
            }
        }
        if(bitmaps.size() > 0){
            for(int i = 0;i<(bitmaps.size());i++){
                if(bitmaps.get(i).rectscale.contains((int)mX,(int) mY)){
                    lastBitmap = i;
                    isScalling  = true;
                    tempx = mX+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getWidth();
                    tempy = mY+bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).bitmap.getHeight();
                }
            }
        }
        if(bitmaps.size() > 0){
            for(int i = 0;i<(bitmaps.size());i++){
                if(bitmaps.get(i).rectrotate.contains((int)mX,(int) mY)){
                    lastBitmap = i;
                    isRotating = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if ((dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) || (dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        Log.d("move", "mx, my=" + mX + " " + mY);
        // mPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
    }
    // invalidate();
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    mPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
    //        canvas.save();
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
    if(PaintActivity.isPic == 1){
        if(isScalling){
            isScalling = false;
        }
        if(isRotating){
            isRotating = false;
        }
        lastBitmap = bitmaps.size()-1;
        mX= bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).pX;
        mY= bitmaps.get(lastBitmap).pY;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);

        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If i comment the following lines:

```
canvas.setMatrix(matrixRotate);
```

AND:

```
canvas.setMatrix(null);
```

It all works, except for the rotation. But if i don't comment them, the rotation works, the first picture is ok, but for the rest of the pictures, the rectangles are a bit messed up. They do not start in the top-left of the bitmap (where my scale circle is), instead it starts, somewhere lower, almost at the half of the bitmap. So i can use my scale and rotate functions, but i have to guess where to put my finger, because, the point where the circle is drawn is not contained in the Rects. Any ideeas how i could fix this?

EDIT:
I tried: before setting the matrix to matrix rotate:

```
origMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();
```

and instead of:

```
canvas.setMatrix(null);
```

I tried:

```
canvas.setMatrix(origMatrix);
```

It still messed up my rectangles, but at least now it draws the circles for rotating and scalling where the rectangles are (usually somewhere in the middle of the bitmap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this instead:

```
canvas.save();
matrixRotate.setRotate(bitmaps.get(i).rectrotateVal, bitmaps.get(i).pX+(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getWidth() / 2), bitmaps.get(i).pY+(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap.getHeight() / 2));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps.get(i).bitmap, matrixRotate , mBitmapPaint);
canvas.restore();
```